# How to disable warning about overwriting an extension in the vscode Extension Development Host?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Whenever you start a debugging session in vscode to test an extension under development, a warning is shown in the Extension Development Host that your extension will be overwritten (if you have it also installed normally, e.g. the currently published one). After a while this warning really gets annyoing and I wonder how to suppress it. Anyone knows?

**Update**: a while ago I opened a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26276) for this on Github.

Comment: The VS Code team created [another one](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62316) which is planned for April/2019 milestone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning was been removed from VS Code in v1.37:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/89f5c6075fa103457d14cdb0b7c3ee26b2c30afc