# vscode extension: how to prevent development-related fields automatically added to package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

A few times in vscode extension development vscode has automatically added information to the extension's `package.json` that obviously seems related to development and debugging that extension.

Note: that the Marketplace Released version of the extension is also installed in the same workspaces used for debugging in the extensionHost.  Could that be the issue?

The following fields were automatically added to the extension's `package.json`:

```
 "identifier": {
  "value": "ArturoDent.find-and-transform",
  "_lower": "arturodent.find-and-transform"
 },
 "isBuiltin": false,
 "isUserBuiltin": false,
 "isUnderDevelopment": true,
 "extensionLocation": {
  "$mid": 1,
  "fsPath": "c:\\Users\\Mark\\find-and-transform",
  "_sep": 1,
  "external": "file:///c%3A/Users/Mark/find-and-transform",
  "path": "/c:/Users/Mark/find-and-transform",
  "scheme": "file"
 },
 "targetPlatform": "undefined",
```

I missed looking for these changes and published the extension to the Marketplace and it understandably causes problems for users.  The extension never loads for example, probably looking in that location from my development machine.

I do a lot of extension development and have only seen this info automatically added a few times.

Is there a way to prevent that info from being added?  Or change my workflow so it doesn't happen again?

Comment: I have never seen this behavior, I also have my extensions installed from the Marketplace but they are disable when debugging so the new code is running. What you could try is delete the `AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\??????\state.vscdb`, this was the cause for a very strange problem I had with debugging extensions (Extension host was sometimes not able to start), you loose all your workspace state but it could be the solution (you can backup the file in case)

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks, I have twice published extensions that had those package.json keys silently added.  It is a pain because it keeps working on my machine - the directory locations are accurate for me but no one else.  I don't know the pattern of when it happens or why - I will probably file a GH issue.  Seems to me it shouldn't overwrite the package.json that I am testing.  If it was limited to the extensionHost version that's fine.  Now I have to check the package.json for additional changes each time.

Comment: maybe you can write a script that checks the state of `package.json` before calling `vcse publish`, also the modified state of `package.json` should be an indication. I always check the diff of the files before I commit them to see if some edit has sneaked in. I once forgot to run the rollup to generate a new version of the web-extension (It was a very little edit to fix a bug, easy fix .....)

Comment: @rioV8 I always bump the version number in package.json so it would almost always be in the changed files anyway.  So I would have to look for the specific keys it might have added.  I am beginning to wonder if `vsce package` is doing the over-writing.  Then I typically immediately do a `vsce publish`, so I'll have to keep an eye on the changed files to see if package.json changed after `vsce package` (just a guess) - or stop doing the `vsce package` which I never use.

Comment: I never do a `vsce package`, this is not needed to publish to the marketplace

Comment: This looks highly related to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148975 - but that involved running tests rather than just debugging.  Will see if the issue happens again...

Comment: Related question (but the warning has since been removed): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43742576/how-to-disable-warning-about-overwriting-an-extension-in-the-vscode-extension-de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closely related issue was reported at [vscode extension test run modifies package.json after 1.67.0](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148975), where extra metdata was being written to `package.json` without warning and causing all kinds of problems.

The current SO question above here had nothing to do with running tests (as in the github issue) but only with debugging and was quite sporadic and difficult to make recur - but the same metadata was being written to `package.json`.

I have filed a new issue on this: [Extraneous data written to package.json while debugging an extension that writes to package.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/161286)